# Filter list by date in two ways

Tags: python, list

I want to sort some list by dates and filter out some integers which are older than `now - days_count` days or too many ints (more than keep_count) in the list. Here is what I have now:

```
def __get_datetime_by_int(some_int):
    #return some_datetime

def __project_tmp_older_then(int_lst, days_count, keep_count):
    int_lst.sort(key = lambda some_int: __get_date_by_int(some_int), reverse = True)
    old_ints = [some_int for some_int in int_lst 
        if (datetime.now() - __get_datetime_by_int(some_int)).days >= days_count or 
            int_lst.index(some_int) > keep_count]
    return old_ints
```

The problem is I invoke `__get_datetime_by_int` twice on each element of the `int_lst`. I would like to use list or generator comprehension for consciesness.

How to optimize this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def filtered(int_lst):
    """ Generator yielding the first `keep_count` dates older than `days_count`"""
    for some_int in int_lst[keep_count:]:
        date_from_int =  __get_date_by_int(some_int)

        if (datetime.now() - date_from_int).days >= days_count:
            yield some_int, date_from_int


old_ints = sorted(filtered(int_lst), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: Not exactly, we need to take all except first `keep_count` in sorted list.

Comment: It would be great if you could give a short explanation in addition to the source code. This would greatly benefit comprehension.

Comment: @St.Antario Good point. I have edited the solution accordingly.